# How to retrieve a list of all connected COM devices

Tags: serial-port, jna, device

i do need a list of all connected COM devices (in this case my programm has to detect if an Arduino microcontroller is connected to my PC). I can't use the Windows registry as it is not dynamic. In the end my program should only offer a list of COM Ports where an arduino is connected to.

I already had a look at the JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) but it is really complex and i couldn't figure out if and how i can use it to access the information i need.

Hope you can provide help or examples.

EDIT:

The suggested solution is provided in C-Code, i need a solution for my java written program. Anyone can help?

Comment: I had a look at the other post and it doesn't help me as that solution is using C Code...that classes aren't available in Java

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+wmi+query&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: I still couldn't manage to get access to the WMI sorry. I tried to use http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/ but this one wouldn't even start. I also had a look at j-interop but i found it just to confusing as i am not a java expert and just want to execute the `SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity` to extract the names of the installed devices...can someone try to explain how this is done?